# glossaries(extra) document available labels

Tags: glossaries, labels, glossaries-extra

We share our glossaries and symbols in our institute and I want to document what glossaries and symbols are available and what their label is. Hence I use `\glsaddall{}` which works like a charm. As a last step I want to change the appearance of the table to also show the label in front of any entry. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the label using the `\glscurrententrylabel` command for your personal glossary stlye, i.e.

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\loadglsentries{example-glossaries-brief}

\newglossarystyle{labelStyle}{%
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\begin{longtable}{p{.2\textwidth}p{.3\textwidth}p{.5\textwidth}}}%
        {\end{longtable}}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%                   setting the table's header
        \bfseries  & \bfseries Label & \bfseries Description
        \\\tabularnewline\endhead}%
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%              no heading between groups
    \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%                    main entries displayed 
        \textbf{\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}}% name
        & \glscurrententrylabel%                        label
        & \glossentrydesc{##1}%                         description
        \tabularnewline%                                end of row
    }%
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%                    no distance between groups
}

\begin{document} 
    \glsaddall
    \printglossary[style=labelStyle]
\end{document}
```

[image]